# How to deploy multiple cloud functions that are newly pushed using google cloud build and Source Repository?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, build-triggers, google-cloud-repository

I have a project folder with different cloud functions folders e.g.

```
Project_Folder
    -Cloud-Function-Folder1
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
         -cloudbuild.yaml
    -Cloud-Function-Folder2
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
         -cloudbuild.yaml
    -Cloud-Function-Folder3
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
         -cloudbuild.yaml
            --------- and so on!
```

Now what i have right now is. I push the code to the Source Repository one by one from the Cloud Fucntions folder to Source Repository(Separate Repos for each function folder). And then it has a Trigger enabled which trigger the cloud-build and then deploy the function.
The cloudbuild.yaml file i have is like this below..

```
 steps:

 - name: 'python:3.7'
 entrypoint: 'bash'
 args: 
   - '-c'
   - |
       pip3 install -r requirements.txt
       pytest

 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions 
  - deploy
  - Function
  - --runtime=python37
  - --source=.
  - --entry-point=function_main
  - --trigger-topic=Function
  - --region=europe-west3
```

Now, what I would like to do is I would like to make a single source repo and whenever i change the code in one cloud function and push it then only it get deploys and rest remains like before.

---

### Update

Now i have also tried something like this below but it also deploy all the functions at the same time even though i am working on a single function.

```
Project_Folder
    -Cloud-Function-Folder1
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
    -Cloud-Function-Folder2
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
    -Cloud-Function-Folder3
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
    -cloudbuild.yaml
    -requirements.txt
```

cloudbuild.yaml file looks like this below

```
 steps:

 - name: 'python:3.7'
 entrypoint: 'bash'
 args: 
   - '-c'
   - |
       pip3 install -r requirements.txt
       pytest

 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions 
  - deploy
  - Function1
  - --runtime=python37
  - --source=./Cloud-Function-Folder1
  - --entry-point=function1_main
  - --trigger-topic=Function1
  - --region=europe-west3  

 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions 
  - deploy
  - Function2
  - --runtime=python37
  - --source=./Cloud-Function-Folder2
  - --entry-point=function2_main
  - --trigger-topic=Function2
  - --region=europe-west3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more complex et you have to play with limit and constraint of Cloud Build.

I do this:

- get the directory updated since the previous commit
- loop on this directory and do what I want

---

**Hypothesis 1**: all the subfolders are deployed by using the same commands

So, for this I put a `cloudbuild.yaml` at the root of my directory, and not in the subfolders

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
        # Cloud Build doesn't recover the .git file. Thus checkout the repo for this
        git clone --branch $BRANCH_NAME https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/cloudbuildtest.git /tmp/repo ;
        # Copy only the .git file
        mv /tmp/repo/.git .
        # Make a diff between this version and the previous one and store the result into a file
        git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AMDR @~..@ | grep "/" | cut -d"/" -f1 | uniq > /workspace/diff

# Do what you want, by performing a loop in to the directory
- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
       for i in $$(cat /workspace/diff); do
       cd $$i
           # No strong isolation between each function, take care of conflicts!!
           pip3 install -r requirements.txt
           pytest
       cd ..
       done

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
       for i in $$(cat /workspace/diff); do
       cd $$i
           gcloud functions deploy .........           
       cd ..
       done
```

---

**Hypothesis 2**: the deployment is specific by subfolder

So, for this I put a `cloudbuild.yaml` at the root of my directory, and another one in the subfolders

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
        # Cloud Build doesn't recover the .git file. Thus checkout the repo for this
        git clone --branch $BRANCH_NAME https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/cloudbuildtest.git /tmp/repo ;
        # Copy only the .git file
        mv /tmp/repo/.git .
        # Make a diff between this version and the previous one and store the result into a file
        git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AMDR @~..@ | grep "/" | cut -d"/" -f1 | uniq > /workspace/diff

# Do what you want, by performing a loop in to the directory. Here launch a cloud build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
       for i in $$(cat /workspace/diff); do
       cd $$i
           gcloud builds submit
       cd ..
       done
```

Be careful to the [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2) here, because you can trigger a lot of Cloud Build and it take times.

---

Want to run manually your build, don't forget to add the $BRANCH_NAME as substitution variable

```
gcloud builds submit --substitutions=BRANCH_NAME=master
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward, however you need to control the behavior on the Build Trigger side of things and not on the `cloudbuild.yaml`. Conceptually, you want to limit the cloud build trigger behavior and limit it to certain changes within a repo.

As such, make use of the regEx glob include filter in the Build Trigger page:

[image: screenshot of input files glob filter on GCP triggers]

You will build one *trigger per cloud function* (or cloud run) and set the "Included files filter (glob)" as follows:

- Cloud-Function1-Trigger

  Project_Folder/Cloud-Function-Folder1/**
- Cloud-Function2-Trigger

  Project_Folder/Cloud-Function-Folder2/**

...

Assumptions:

1. For each trigger the repo and branch is set such that the root of the repo has the Project_Folder/
2. Repo and branch is appropriately set to so that the trigger can locate and access files in path Project_Folder/Cloud-Function-Folder1/*

When I have more than 2-3 cloud function, I tend to use Terraform to create all the required triggers in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a folder for each of the functions like this

```
Project_Folder
    -Cloud-Function-Folder1
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
         -cloudbuild.yaml
    -Cloud-Function-Folder2
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
         -cloudbuild.yaml
    -Cloud-Function-Folder3
         -main.py
         -requirements.txt
         -cloudbuild.yaml
            --------- and so on!
```

and create a `cloudbuild.yaml` in each dir which would look like this

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - Cloud_Function_1
      - --source=.
      - --trigger-http
      - --runtime=python37
      - --allow-unauthenticated
    dir: "Cloud-Function-Folder1"
```

on the cloud build create a trigger with included file filter to only include files from the `functions-folder-name` and also manually specify `functions-folder-name/cloudbuild.yaml` for each of the triggers.

From [this](https://torbjornzetterlund.com/using-cloud-build-as-you-ci-co-for-multiple-cloud-functions/) blog post by Torbjorn Zetterlund you can read the entire process of deploying multiple cloud functions from single github repo with include filter to only deploy changed function.

Answer (score -3):

If you create a single source repo and change your code as one cloud function you have to create a single ['cloudbuild.yaml' configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config). You need to connect this single repo to Cloud Build. Then create a [build trigger](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger) select this repo as a Source. Also you need to [configure deployment](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions#continuous_deployment) and anytime you push new code to your repository, you will automatically trigger a build and deploy on Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thats what i am doing right now. what i would like to do is i would like to make a single repo with different cloud functions. if i change e.g. Cloud-function1 then it should only trigger the deployment of this cloud function